# Can i repeat the template in the below html based on the dropdown selected value using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page. The issue which I am facing is I am unable to come up with a method to display multiple templates based on the dropdown value 'Number of Chasis'. For example if I select Number of Chasis as 2 from the dropdown, I want the template to be displayed twice and that too horizontally and not vertically. Is there any way to achieve that? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

````
            <fieldset id='extra'>
                <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller A</h6>
                <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
                    <select name='Controller_ID1' required>
                    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
                    <option value='A'>A </select>
                <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips'  disabled="disabled" />
                <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1'  placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
                <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
                <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
                <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
                <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)"/> 
                <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
<br>
<br>
                <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller B</h6>
                <label for='Controller_ID'>Controller_ID:</label>
                    <select name='Controller_ID' id="ctlid" required>
                    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
                    <option value='B'>B </select>
                <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
                <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba1" name='hba_ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
                <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip' id='mcip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP'  /> 
                <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip' id="netmaskip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
                <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip' id="gatewayip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway'  /> 
                <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' id="rbodmc"onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' id="rbodsc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' id="rbodfu" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' id="rbodec" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 

            </fieldset>
        </template> 

    <fieldset>
                <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Number of Chasis</strong></label>
                <select input type='text' name='chassis'   required >
                <option value=""> - Number of Controllers - </option>
                <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
                <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
                </select>
            </fieldset> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

```js
function remove_all_dom() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.chasie'), function(dom) {
    document.body.removeChild(dom)
  })
}

function on_change(dom) {
  remove_all_dom()
  var value = dom.value
  for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
    var copy_dom = document.querySelector('#extra').cloneNode(true)
    copy_dom.setAttribute('id', 'extra' + i)
    copy_dom.classList.add('chasie')
    document.body.insertBefore(copy_dom, document.querySelector('#insertbefore'))
  }
}
```

```css
.divide {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.divide:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id='extra'>
  <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller A</h6>
  <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
  <select name='Controller_ID1' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='A'>A </select>
  <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
  <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
  <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
  <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller B</h6>
  <label for='Controller_ID'>Controller_ID:</label>
  <select name='Controller_ID' id="ctlid" required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='B'>B </select>
  <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba1" name='hba_ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
  <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip' id='mcip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
  <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip' id="netmaskip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
  <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip' id="gatewayip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
  <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' id="rbodmc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' id="rbodsc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' id="rbodfu" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
  <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' id="rbodec" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset id="insertbefore">
  <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Number of Chasis</strong></label>
  <select input type='text' name='chassis' required onChange="on_change(this)">
    <option value=""> - Number of Controllers - </option>
    <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
      <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

```js
function on_change(dom) {
  var value = dom.value
  if (value == 2) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.chasie'), function(node) {
      node.classList.add('divide')
    })
  } else {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.chasie'), function(node) {
      node.classList.remove('divide')
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.divide {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.divide:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id='extra'>
  <div class="chasie">
    <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller A</h6>
    <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
    <select name='Controller_ID1' required>
      <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
      <option value='A'>A </select>
    <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
    <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
    <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
    <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
    <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
    <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
    <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
    <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
    <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="chasie">
    <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller B</h6>
    <label for='Controller_ID'>Controller_ID:</label>
    <select name='Controller_ID' id="ctlid" required>
      <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
      <option value='B'>B </select>
    <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
    <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba1" name='hba_ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
    <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip' id='mcip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
    <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip' id="netmaskip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
    <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip' id="gatewayip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
    <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' id="rbodmc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
    <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' id="rbodsc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
    <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' id="rbodfu" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />
    <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' id="rbodec" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" />

</fieldset>
</div>

<fieldset>
  <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Number of Chasis</strong></label>
  <select input type='text' name='chassis' required onChange="on_change(this)">
    <option value=""> - Number of Controllers - </option>
    <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
      <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Drop down selection could change the css display-attribute of your elements, so that you can display:hide whatever you dont want to show. Same for your horizontal goal, maybe check out css-grid:

[Genious and easy guide for css-grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Otherwhise I recomend using litelement, which is a gread and easy-to-use library for creating/manipulating and wworking with templates.

[Lit-element getting started tutorial](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/)

Comment: thanks for the response. I am looking for a js function by which I can display the template multiple times based on user input